# dabbrev-expand and dabbrev-completion inconsistent?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Using GNU emacs 24.3 on Windows 7

I've found a few words that dabbrev-expand and dabbrev-completion don't seem to treat consistently. For example, if I type:

```
chars_CHA C-M-/
```

There will be a message (from dabbrev-completion) of 'No match found.'.

However, if I then run dabbrev-expand (M-/, I think, I'm not using either of these bindings), it will cycle through a few completions; chars_CHARS, chars_CHARIZARD, chars_charslower, etc.

Shouldn't dabbrev-completion provide a list of completions, rather than telling me no match whenever dabbrev-expand can find multiple matches? In most situations, dabbrev-completion behaves as expected and brings up a completion window.

EDIT: Neither of the prefix arguments suggested by dabbrev-completions documentation seem to help (or be relevant, as the missing completions can occur in the current buffer).

Answer (score 1):

The doc strings of those two commands tell you that `dabbrev-expand` looks also "*in the
buffers accepted by the function pointed out by variable
`dabbrev-friend-buffer-function`*", and that `dabbrev-completion` does that ***only*** *if you use a prefix arg*. So try a prefix arg with the latter, if you expect it to act similarly.

---

**Update, replying to your comment:**

If `C-u C-u` doesn't help then searching all buffers does not help. And since you say that those candidates occur in the same buffer, then this is irrelevant.

(You might check your values of `dabbrev-case-fold-search`, `dabbrev-upcase-means-case-search`, `dabbrev-case-distinction`, and `dabbrev-case-replace`.  But you will see whether any of these is a problem if you debug (see next).)

You can debug what is actually happening by loading `dabbrev.el` (not `dabbrev.elc`) and doing `M-x debug-on-entry RET dabbrev-completion RET`.

IOW, unless someone else sees something obvious, you will need to see why there is a difference in your context.

Comment: Unfortunately, C-u dabbrev-completion behaves just as it does without the prefix argument. And additionally, it is failing to find matches in the current buffer. I'll get "no match" for chars_CH even if chars_CHARS appears in the buffer a dozen times.

edit: And as long as we're talking about the docstring, using a prefix arg of 16 (C-u C-u) doesn't help either.